# Angular2 - external package version mismatch with angular version

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload, angular

My angular2 project is build off the old RC4, but im tyring to add [ng2-file-upload](http://valor-software.com/ng2-file-upload/) module to my project. When I do I get

```
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@2.0.0-rc.4
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@2.0.0-rc.4
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.4
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/forms@2.0.0
├── ng2-file-upload@1.1.0 
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY parse5@^1.5.0
npm WARN ng2-file-upload@1.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@2.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN ng2-file-upload@1.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@2.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN ng2-file-upload@1.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN ng2-file-upload@1.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/forms@2.0.0 but none was installed.
```

Is there a way to use this module, or get an older version of this module for RC4 ?

Comment: can you please share your package.json?

Comment: NgModule was introduced in angular2 RC5 version.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the version you use for ng2-file-upload requires a newer version of angular 2. You actually use version 2.0.0-rc.4
You can see it inside the package.json of the [project](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload/blob/development/package.json).
You should consider using an older version of ng2-file-upload or upgrade to angular 2.0.0

As I see version 1.0.3 uses angular2 rc1, maybe RC4 compatible with this version. try to use this version of ng2-file-upload and see if works.
You can specify the version you use inside your package.json file

Comment: Right, is there a way to use it in my rc4 project? Or am i doomed to not have it ?

Comment: I see that they have two older versions 1.0.3 and 1.0.2 you can try downloading the source code and see what version of angular it use

Comment: Updated my answer, please see - consider use version 1.0.3